# Unit tests to javascript classes (ES6) - Stubs not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

I have a problem with unit tests in a javascript (react) project.
Wanted to test the ApiClient class. For this I will have to isolate settingsApi, HttpClient and resources.
I using tools: mocha, chai, sinon

I also tried using rewire and I could not. I already read that it could be because of babel.

I've tried stubs like this:

```
sinon.stub(ApiClient.prototype, 'constructor');
```

Has anyone had this problem, can you give me a hand?

Below is part of the code:

File ApiClient.js

```
import settingsApi from '../../settings/api.json';
import HttpClient from './HttpClient';
import resources from './resources';

class ApiClient {
  constructor() {
    this.httpClient = new HttpClient(settingsApi);
  }

  get flux() {
    return new resources.resourceOne(this.httpClient);
  }
}

export default ApiClient;
```

FileHttpClient.js

```
class HttpClient {
/**
 * 
 * @param {*} config 
 */
constructor(config) {
    this.basePath = `${config.protocol}://${config.host}:${config.port}`;
}

post(resource, options = {}, formatResponse) {
    return this.request({
        method: 'POST',
        resource,
        options,
        formatResponse
    });
}


export default HttpClient;
```

Comment: Just a sidenote: `sinon.stub(ApiClient.prototype, 'contructor');` has a spelling error. Should be `constructor`

Comment: Thanks, I already changed it.

Comment: I don't think you can stub a class by setting the `constructor` property on its prototype

Comment: I've experimented with and without prototype and it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could already solve my problem, I used the babel-plugin-rewire (https://github.com/speedskater/babel-plugin-rewire):

Installation:

```
yarn add babel-core babel-plugin-rewire --dev
```

Add to .babelrc

```
"plugins": [
    "rewire"
]
```

Mock the dependencies example:

```
ApiClient.__Rewire__('settingsApi', {
  paramConfig: 'config',
});

ApiClient.__Rewire__('HttpClient', class HttpClient {
    constructor(config) {
    }
});

ApiClient.__Rewire__('resources', {
    resourceOne: class {
       constructor(httpClient) {       
       }
});
```

Now instead of calling the dependencies calls the above functions.